# List of Transforms editable from Inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on Unity 5, and I need to create a list of transforms in order to modify them in the inspector (position and rotation) to emulate a different camera. This emulation is for a demo, like a camera moving on its own during the demo.

I currently have a list of transforms, but I don't know how to make them modifiable in the inspector and change their position at runtime?

Edit: 18/11/15

Here is the solution that if find with a help of a friend of mine more aware of what really does unity, hope it will help you and thanks again for all your reply it helped me a lot :D :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MoveCamera : MonoBehaviourSingleton<MoveCamera>
{
    public List<Transform> cameraPositions = new List<Transform>();

    private Transform m_Target;
    private float m_Speed;
    private bool m_Translate;
    private bool m_Rotate;

    public void SwitchToNext(int index, float speed)
    {
        m_Target = cameraPositions[index];
        m_Translate = true;
        m_Rotate = true;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (m_Target != null && (m_Translate || m_Rotate))
        {
            float ratio = Time.deltaTime * m_Speed;
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, m_Target.position, ratio);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, m_Target.rotation, ratio);

            if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, m_Target.position) < 0.001f)
            {
                transform.position = m_Target.position;
                m_Translate = false;
            }
            if (Quaternion.Angle(transform.rotation, m_Target.rotation) < 0.001f)
            {
                transform.rotation = m_Target.rotation;
                m_Rotate = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Can you show us some code?

Comment: I had to erase my code last night in a access of nerves ^^ but i looks like that : `public class MoveCamera : MonoBehavior<Singleton>
{
 
        void Start()
        { List<Transform> myList = new List<Transform>}`

Comment: I think this won't work directly but maybe there are other ways to accomplish that indirectly e..g marker interface, tag, ... Sounds like a start / end position thing. So it's interesting to know what is the purpose? Can you attach a MonBehaviour to the target objects?

Comment: The purpose it's to be able to place different transform all over the scene and then define the position you want for each transform in the list. Then to be able to switch between them to see a different view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest just a simple public list in your `MoveCamera` script and then dragging the targets into that list. Doing it this way you have full control over the order of the objects and thus you can do animated transitions from camera position *n* to *n + 1*.

```
public List<Transform> cameraPositions = new List<Transform> ();
```

Maybe a simple sequence does not fit your requirements and you need a more sophisticated way to decide which position is allowed to switch to which other position. In this case I'd suggest a helper script e.g. `CameraTransition.cs`. Here you can place your check logic and definition parameters.

Attach this to every allowed target position object and replace the list in `MoveCamera` by `List<CameraTransition>`.

Answer (score 2):

Ok lets see if this helps you.(i will write my code assuming you want this)
You have x gameObjects in your scene.

You will need a GameObject List. Lets say you get them by doing

```
public List<GameObject> myObjectList = new List<GameObject>();
public List<Transform> myTransformList =  new List<Transform>();
myObjectList = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("YourCustomTagHere");

foreach(Gameobject g in myObjectList)
{
 myTransformList.Add(g.transform);
}
```

I dont know if this code works, i cant test it right now, but i think the logic is there. Go ahead and try a few things, give some feedback whether you made it or not.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer ! I will try this but the main problem that i have it's how can i manage to edit this in the inspector ? Is this going to be editable in the inspector, will i be able to add many transform as i want ? Do they will have all the position and rotation transform has ?

Comment: Wwhen you declare a variable as `public` it will be visible in the inspector. However in this case it is a list of Transforms, so i dont know, sry. But i would like to know that, if you have the opportunity to test this give me some feedback.

Comment: Thank you again for your answers ! I'm not able to test it now as long as i'm at work but when i go back to my house i will test it and give you a feedback !

Comment: You're welcome, sadly i cant test it either but good luck with your project.
Happy coding.

Comment: Hey, it didn't work but i find a solution hope it will help you too thanks a lot

Comment: I figured it might not work, did some reseachr. try this .
http://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/editor/custom-list/